# PHP Undefined Index

Tags: php

I have this code and it's giving me an undefined error if country is not a variable in the URL. I've never had this problem before so it's obviously something to do with server settings but I'd rather not change those because this is probably done for security purposes. I've searched Google and can't find the workaround, although I'm sure it's blindingly obvious!

```
$country = $_GET['country'];

    if(!$country){
        $incoming = $outgoing = $sms = $free = "---";
    } else {
        get_rates($country);
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you should use the following approach:

```
if (!isset($_GET['country'])) {
    $incoming = $outgoing = $sms = $free = "---";
} else {
    get_rates($_GET['country']);
}
```

Comment: Actually, I think you want if(!isset(...)) {

Comment: You are missing a closing ']' bracket in the if statement

Comment: $country = @$_GET['country'];  // the OLD PHP way to avoid notices

Answer (score 4):

isset allows you to check if the variable exists (if not we give it the value false).

```
$country = isset($_GET['country'])?  $_GET['country'] : false;
```

Answer (score 2):

`"Undefined index"` means that element doesn't exist in the array. Your server is probably set to report these errors, while your system so far wasn't. Check if the element exists before accessing it.

```
$country = null;
if (!empty($_GET['country']) {
    $country = $_GET['country'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably check to see if $_GET['country'] is set. I would wrap the entire code block you posted in an `if` statement that checks if the country field is set, using the [`isset`](https://www.php.net/isset) function.

Answer (score -1):

Just change:

```
$country = $_GET['country'];
```

To this:

```
$country = @$_GET['country'];
```

'@' is an operator which will remove errors output.

Comment: that's the worst piece of advice one could give

Comment: In this case it's ok because there's a check just after.

Comment: using @ error supressor is quite a stinky code smell, read about code smells on SO

Comment: @ IS OK for some contexts, in conscious use. It is NOT A DEPRECATED operator. The main typical use is with $_POST and $_GET, like '<input name="x" value="<?= $_POST['x']?>"/>'.  The FWH suggestion is good:  initialize $contry with '' or with a value, there are NO SIDE EFFECT!