# PHP error: Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php, variables, indexing, undefined

I am working on a shopping cart in PHP and I seem to be getting this error "Notice: Undefined index:" in all sorts of places. The error refers to the similar bit of coding in different places. For example I have a piece of coding that calculates a package price with the months a user decides to subscribe. I have the following variables where the errors refers to:

```
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $op = $_POST['op'];
```

The $month variable is the number the user inputs in a form, and the $op variable is different packages whose value are stored in a vriable that a user selects from radio buttons on the form.

I hope that is clear in some way.

Thank You

EDIT: Sorry forgot to mention that they do go away when the user submits the data. But when they first come to the page it displays this error. How I can get rid of it so it doesnt display it?

--

This is the code:

```
<?php
    $pack_1 = 3;
    $pack_2 = 6;
    $pack_3 = 9;
    $pack_4 = 12;
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $op = $_POST['op'];
    $action = $_GET['action'];

    if ( $op == "Adopter" ) {
       $answer = $pack_1 * $month;
    }

    if ( $op == "Defender" ) {
      $answer = $pack_2 * $month;
    }

    if ( $op == "Protector" ) {
      $answer = $pack_3 * $month;
    }

    if ( $op == "Guardian" ) {
      $answer = $pack_4 * $month;
    }

    switch($action) {   
        case "adds":
            $_SESSION['cart'][$answer][$op];
            break;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please post the rest of your code.  The undefined index error means the post data for that key is not being sent, the indexes being 'month' and 'op'.  Something is either setting this back to NULL or they are not being sent at all and there is a problem with the form.

Comment: Please put your whole code...so we can review it.

Comment: EDIT: Sorry forgot to mention that they do go away when the user submits the data. But when they first come to the page it displays this error. How I can get rid of it so it doesnt display it?

Comment: Check if the user is submitting?

Comment: Exact duplicate of about a million questions, starting with [PHP Undefined Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136979/php-undefined-index)

Comment: @PHPNOOB Please say thank you to all users. At least accept ONE answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 28):

You're attempting to access indicies within an array which are not set. This raises a notice.

Mostly likely you're noticing it now because your code has moved to a server where php.ini has `error_reporting` set to include `E_NOTICE`. Either suppress notices by setting error_reporting to `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` (not recommended), or verify that the index exists before you attempt to access it:

```
$month = array_key_exists('month', $_POST) ? $_POST['month'] : null;
```

Answer (score 13):

Are you putting the form processor in the same script as the form?  If so, it is attempting to process before the post values are set (everything is executing).

Wrap all the processing code in a conditional that checks if the form has even been sent.

```
if(isset($_POST) && array_key_exists('name_of_your_submit_input',$_POST)){
//process form!
}else{
//show form, don't process yet!  You can break out of php here and render your form
}
```

Scripts execute from the top down when programming procedurally.  You need to make sure the program knows to ignore the processing logic if the form has not been sent.  Likewise, after processing, you should redirect to a success page with something like

```
header('Location:http://www.yourdomainhere.com/formsuccess.php');
```

I would not get into the habit of supressing notices or errors.

Please don't take offense if I suggest that if you are having these problems and you are attempting to build a shopping cart, that you instead utilize a mature ecommerce solution like Magento or OsCommerce.  A shopping cart is an interface that requires a high degree of security and if you are struggling with these kind of POST issues I can guarantee you will be fraught with headaches later.  There are many great stable releases, some as simple as mere object models, that are available for download.

Comment: hi, yes the form is on the same page as the script, so i think that is one of the problem, putting the error reporting code has removed the error now, but im having problems with other bits of code, so i think i really need to restructure everything!

Comment: Unfortunately i cant use any off the shelf cart as it is part of an assignemnt where we have to build a dynamic website in php where users can adopt animals etc, so have to program it from scratch, and its been made more complex by the way the lecturer wants the whole thing done,

Comment: Ah, so then this would be homework.  That's a bit of a finicky word around these parts lol.

http://www.webforcecart.com/

Comment: Check out how adding and removing items is handled in that class.  Should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Due to [newbees possible misunderstanding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158800/is-array-key-existssubmit-input-name-post-better-than-postmm-insert): `$_POST` is always set regardless of sapi, or whether it's a GET or POST (HEAD, PUT, ..), unless explicitly disabled in `variables_order` (PHP_INI_DIR since php 5.0.5, so if disables there it's probably always disabled for the file). Summarizing the above with only `isset($_POST['name_of_your_submit_input'])` is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously $_POST['month'] is not set. Maybe there's a mistake in your HTML form definition, or maybe something else is causing this. Whatever the cause, you should always check if a variable exists before using it, so

```
if(isset($_POST['month'])) {
   $month = $_POST['month'];
} else {
   //month is not set, do something about it, raise an error, throw an exception, orwahtever
}
```

Comment: I personally avoid 'is_set', as it returns false if `$_POST['month']` has been set to `null`. When you really mean to ask if the array key exists, use `array_key_exists`.

Comment: @meagar: It's unlikely that any `$_POST[]` var contains a `NULL` if it originates from `multipart/form-data`. That would only be an issue if subfunctions inject state via $_POST, which should be way more worriesome then differentiating between null and unset.

Answer (score 2):

> How I can get rid of it so it doesnt display it?

People here are trying to tell you that it's unprofessional (and it is), but in your case you should simply add following to the start of your application:

```
 error_reporting(E_ERROR|E_WARNING);
```

This will disable E_NOTICE reporting. E_NOTICES are not errors, but notices, as the name says. You'd better check this stuff out and proof that undefined variables don't lead to errors. But the common case is that they are just informal, and perfectly normal for handling form input with PHP.

Also, next time Google the error message first.

Comment: Judging from his last comment, I think he isn't checking first for form submission.  The notices are raised because whatever processing is taking place on data that hasn't been sent yet.

Comment: @DeaconDesperado: Likely. The one snippet looks as if the $_POST input vars are just localized at the start of the script no matter what. Processing might be triggered by another `if` or just boolean state of one of those variables. ... We'll never find out :}

Comment: and so it will remain one of the great mysteries of our age... which won't stop it from being posted again and again and again lol.

Answer (score 2):

This are just php notice messages,it seems php.ini configurations are not according vtiger standards,
you can disable this message by setting **error reporting** to **E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE** in **php.ini**
For example `error_reporting(E_ALL&~E_NOTICE)` and then **restart apache** to reflect changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$month = ( isset($_POST['month']) ) ? $_POST['month'] : '';

$op = ( isset($_POST['op']) ) ? $_POST['op'] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there could be no form elements by name 'month' or 'op'. Can you verify if the HTML source (of the page which results in error when submitted) indeed has html elements by he above names

Answer (score 0):

undefined index means the array key is not set , do a `var_dump($_POST);die();` before the line that throws the error and see that you're trying to get an array key that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

it just means that the array, $_POST in this case, doesn't have an element named what is undefined in your error. PHP issues a NOTICE instead of a WARNING of FATAL ERROR.

You can either log less events via editing php.ini or deal with it by first checking if the items is indeed initialized already by using isset()

Answer (score 0):

apparently, the GET and/or the POST variable(s) do(es) not exist.  simply test if "isset".  (pseudocode):

```
if(isset($_GET['action'];)) {$action = $_GET['action'];} else { RECOVER FROM ERROR CODE }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assure you have used method="post" in the form you are sending data from.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ($_POST['parse_var'] == "contactform"){


        $emailTitle = 'New Email From KumbhAqua';
        $yourEmail = 'xyz@gmail.com';

        $emailField = $_POST['email'];
        $nameField = $_POST['name'];
        $numberField = $_POST['number'];
        $messageField = $_POST['message'];  

        $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
    Email: $emailField <br /> 
    Name:  $nameField <br />
    Message: $messageField <br />


EOD;

    $headers = "from: $emailField\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/htmml\r\n";
    $success =  mail("$yourEmail", "$emailTitle", "$body", "$headers");

    $sent ="Thank You ! Your Message Has Been sent.";

}

?>


 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>:: KumbhAqua ::</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mainHeader">
            <div class="transbox">

              <p><font color="red" face="Matura MT Script Capitals" size="+5">Kumbh</font><font face="Matura MT Script Capitals" size="+5" color=                                                                           "skyblue">Aqua</font><font color="skyblue"> Solution</font></p>
              <p ><font color="skyblue">Your First Destination for Healthier Life.</font></p>
                    <nav><ul>
                        <li> <a href="KumbhAqua.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="aboutus.html">KumbhAqua</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="services.html">Products</a></li>
                        <li  class="active"> <a href="contactus.php">ContactUs</a></li>

                    </ul></nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                    <div class="main">
                        <div class="mainContent">
                            <h1 style="font-size:28px; letter-spacing: 16px; padding-top: 20px; text-align:center; text-transform: uppercase; color:                                    #a7a7a7"><font color="red">Kumbh</font><font color="skyblue">Aqua</font> Symbol of purity</h1>
                                <div class="contactForm">
                                    <form name="contactform" id="contactform" method="POST" action="contactus.php" >
                                        Name :<br />
                                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="30" size="30" value="<?php echo "nameField"; ?>" /><br />
                                         E-mail :<br />
                                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" maxlength="50" size="50" value="<?php echo "emailField"; ?>" /><br />
                                         Phone Number :<br />
                                        <input type="text" id="number" name="number" value="<?php echo "numberField"; ?>"/><br />
                                         Message :<br />
                                        <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="10" cols="20" value="<?php echo "messageField"; ?>" >Some Text...                                        </textarea>
                                        <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="parse_var" id="parse_var" value="contactform" />
                                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"> <br />

                                        <?php  echo "$sent"; ?>

                                    </form>
                                        </div>  
                            <div class="contactFormAdd">

                                    <img src="Images/k1.JPG" width="200" height="200" title="Contactus" />
                                    <h1>KumbhAqua Solution,</h1>
                                    <strong><p>Saraswati Vihar Colony,<br />
                                    New Cantt Allahabad, 211001
                                    </p></strong>
                                    <b>DEEPAK SINGH &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; RISHIRAJ SINGH<br />
                                    8687263459 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;8115120821 </b>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                            <footer class="mainFooter">
                            <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href="KumbhAqua.html"> Home </a></li>
                                <li> <a href="aboutus.html"> KumbhAqua </a></li>
                                <li> <a href="services.html"> Products</a></li>
                                <li class="active"> <a href="contactus.php"> ContactUs </a></li>
                            </ul>
                                <div class="r_footer">


          Copyright &copy; 2015 <a href="#" Title="KumbhAqua">KumbhAqua.in</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Created and Maintained By-   <a title="Randheer                                                                                                                                                                                                                             Pratap Singh "href="#">RandheerSingh</a>                                                                            </div>  
                            </nav>
                            </footer>
    </body>
</html> 

    enter code here
```

Comment: Got two Errors 1) Undefined Index: parse_var 2) Undefined variable sent

Answer (score 0):

I did define all the variables that was the first thing I checked. I know it's not required in PHP, but old habits die hard. Then I sanatized the info like this:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name1"])) {
    $name1Err = " First Name is a required field.";
  } else {
      $name1 = test_input($_POST["name1"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name1)) {
      $name1Err = "Only letters and white space allowed";
```

of course test_input is another function that does a trim, strilashes, and  htmlspecialchars. I think the input is pretty well sanitized. Not trying to be rude just showing what I did. When it came to the email I also checked to see if it was the proper format. I think the real answer is in the fact that some variables are local and some are global. I have got it working without errors for now so, while I'm extremely busy right now I'll accept shutting off errors as my answer. Don't worry I'll figure it out it's just not vitally important right now!

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the  tags correctly closed. And the closing tag will not include inside a loop. (if it contains in a looping structure).

Comment: Please give a more detailed description of your solution.

Comment: In my case the problem solved by replacing form tag;  <td>
    <form id="idsent" name="idsent" method="POST" action="<?php echo site_url('controller/view');?>" >
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $tbln;?>" name="slctdtbl" />
    <input type="radio" id="idradio" name="idradio"   value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> 
   
    </td>
   <td><?=$row['id'];?></td>
   <td> <?=$row['adrs'];?></td>
   <td> <?=$row['ownr'];?></td>
   <td> <?=$row['rmrk'];?></td>
   
 
   echo '</tr>'; 
  }
       ?>
     </form> Like this;  radio button </form> tag close after the looping 
 block.

Comment: You should edit your answer, and add the formatted source code. It's unreadable.