# Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php, html, sql

This is the main.php with a date picker and is pointing to `index.php` where I have the table with data. It work when I pick a date but when I make some changes to the `index.php` page ex: edit data or if I go directly to `index.php` I get :

> Notice: Undefined index: arr_date in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/zeta/index.php on line 112

```
<?php

include 'database.php';

$reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM live");  

$reponse->closeCursor();

?>

  <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="date"  name="arr_date" value="FROM">
    <input type="submit"  value="Search">
  </form>
```

index.php

```
 <?php
 include 'database.php';

 $selected_date= $_POST['arr_date'];

 $reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM live where 
 arr_date='$selected_date'");

while ($row = $reponse->fetch())
{
?>
```

Hi everybody,
thank you for your help, for info this solved my problem:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db.php';

// Check Post variables are available
if(isset($_POST['select_date']))
{
     $_POST['select_date']."";
     // Set session variables
    $_SESSION["select_date"] = $_POST['select_date'];
     $_SESSION["select_date"]."";;
}
else
     $_SESSION["select_date"];
    //echo 'No, form submitted.';

$select_date = $_SESSION["select_date"];


$reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM live where 
select_date='$select_date'");

while ($row = $reponse->fetch())
{
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined index error PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613570/undefined-index-error-php)

Comment: first try to print `$_POST`, and handle this type of things by using `isset()` function.

Comment: your SQL is vulnerable to injection attacks. Learn how to use parameterised queries and prepared statements. http://bobby-tables.com/ has a clear (and humorous) explanation of the risks, plus some info on how to do it properly, including in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, if you go directly to the index.php it is a new request which does not have the form data.

You should check if the form is submitted

```
if(isset($_POST['arr_date'])) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: thx is working no more error but no more data on the page even with refresh, I have to go back and refresh to display data

Comment: @scunja You have to output the form again if it wasn't a POST (and also if the entered values are invalid, eg. in your case the date is empty or not parsable)

Comment: how to solve that? i don't want to submit the form again. Is there a way to keep the index with the $_POST['arr_date] from the form

Comment: if you're interested Ive posted the solution

Answer (score 1):

Use `isset()` or `empty()`

```
<?php
 include 'database.php';

 if(isset($_POST['arr_date']))
 {
   $selected_date= $_POST['arr_date'];

   $reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM live where 
   arr_date='$selected_date'");

  while ($row = $reponse->fetch())
  {
  }
 }

echo "Other code which is not depended on POST will write here";
?>
```

Comment: thx is working no more error but no more data on the page even with refresh, I have to go back and refresh to display data

Comment: Where you want to display? on index page ? @scunja

Comment: When you click submit then form will redirect to index.php page and it will surely give you post data after submit and display it on index.php

Comment: Yes that's right I have post data but when i edit something on index.php after form submit no more data on the page

Comment: Write your other code after complete `if(isset($_POST['arr_date']))` and then check.. Check edited answer @scunja

Comment: I have other form on index.php that change background color of cell, update the cells data, cancel a row etc... so if I perform any of this form the index.php will be empty

Comment: Check edited code and last comment hope it will help... If you still not able to find solution then please paste whole index file in question

Comment: if you're interested Ive posted the solution

Comment: where you have posted ? :)

Comment: at the top of the page, at the end of the original post

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether the variable is set or not.

If it is set, then only go ahead with [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

**Corrected Code:**

```
<?php
include 'database.php';
if (isset($_POST['arr_date'])) {
 $selected_date= $_POST['arr_date'];
 $reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM live where 
 arr_date='$selected_date'");
 while ($row = $reponse->fetch()) {
  // While code
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: thx is working no more error but no more data on the page even with refresh, I have to go back and refresh to display data

Comment: @scunja unless you go there via the submission of your form from the other page, then of course there will be no more data. Visiting index.php directly without form submission makes no sense, because it essentially relies on the data coming from the form. There's no reason to view the page otherwise.

Comment: @ADyson thx but how to correct this stuff? I really don't know

Comment: @scunja I don't know what you want to correct? If your index.php relies on data from the form submission, then why would you try to visit it any other way than via submitting the form?

Comment: yes but after the form submission i want to saty on the index.php and perform other form action on the same page (index.php)

Comment: if you're interested Ive posted the solution

Answer (score 1):

You have to show full code. Whatever probably you are fetching value from array directly like this. $val= $_POST['arr_date'], you have to use isset() function to check if variable is set or not like this.

```
if(isset($_POST['arr_date'])){
   $var = $_POST['arr_date'];
}
```

Comment: thx is working no more error but no more data on the page even with refresh, I have to go back and refresh to display data

Comment: Sorry? , it will show data only when you have submit a form with action "index.php" as i am assuming that this code is on index.php

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if the post data is set or not

```
<?php
 include 'database.php';
 $selected_date= "";//set select date to blank
 if(isset($_POST['arr_date']))
 {
     $selected_date= $_POST['arr_date'];
     $reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM live where arr_date='$selected_date'");

    while ($row = $reponse->fetch())
    {
    }//end of while
}
?>
```

What I've done is used if condition

```
$selected_date= "";//set select date to blank
 if(isset($_POST['arr_date']){
     $selected_date= $_POST['arr_date'];
 }
```

Comment: your code is wrong. it will emit a "Undefined index" as you check the value first(before isset)

Comment: i am not checking the value before `isset`. I am assigning blank data to `$selected_date` as it if used below the code and if `if` statement is not reached it will not generate any error.

Comment: `$selected_date= "";` is pretty much redundant I think

Answer (score 0):

Direct access to undefined array key (array index) results in

> "Notice: Undefined index: KEY_NAME".

Solution:

1. First check if key exists `isset($_POST['KEY'])`
2. If exists, use

Code:

```
if (isset($_POST['KEY'])) {
    // use $_POST['key']
    };
```

Comment: Thank you @RJParikh

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost right but you need to write validation also as follow:

**1st Method :**

```
<?php
 include 'database.php';

 $selected_date= isset($_POST['arr_date'])?$_POST['arr_date']:"";
 if(!empty($selected_date)){
 $reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM live where 
 arr_date='$selected_date'");

  while ($row = $reponse->fetch())
  {
    // Do your stuff here;
   }
 }
?>
```

**2nd Method :**

```
<?php
 include 'database.php';
 $selected_date= "";//set select date to blank
 if(isset($_POST['arr_date']))
 {
     $selected_date= $_POST['arr_date'];
     $reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM live where arr_date='$selected_date'");

    while ($row = $reponse->fetch())
    {

       // Do your stuff here;
       }
     }
?>
```

Comment: i m sorry but is still not displaying data after first action on index.php

Comment: I will be more helpful if post your **error** and how **code snippet**. There is no any complexity. It should display data if data is there.

Comment: thx ive posted the solution at the top of the page, below my original post

Comment: @scunja Great Job buddy... Keep it up .