# How to solve Undefined index: stripeToken in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, stripe-payments

I am getting this error and I have no clue about this and trying to sort out the things and tried many things but nothing works. Kindly check the errors below:

> Notice: Undefined index: stripeToken in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/fullbrick/thankYou.php on line 42 NULL  Fatal error:
>   Uncaught Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest: Must provide source or customer.
>   in /opt/lampp/htdocs/fullbrick/stripe-php/lib/ApiRequestor.php:181
>   from API request 'req_cuGvSG7abb9bzS' Stack trace: #0
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/fullbrick/stripe-php/lib/ApiRequestor.php(144):
>   Stripe\ApiRequestor::_specificAPIError('{\n "error": {\n...', 400,
>   Array, Array, Array) #1
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/fullbrick/stripe-php/lib/ApiRequestor.php(430):
>   Stripe\ApiRequestor->handleErrorResponse('{\n "error": {\n...', 400, 
>   Array, Array) #2
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/fullbrick/stripe-php/lib/ApiRequestor.php(97):
>   Stripe\ApiRequestor->_interpretResponse('{\n "error": {\n...', 400  ,
>   Array) #3
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/fullbrick/stripe-php/lib/ApiOperations/Request.php(56):
>   Stripe\ApiRequestor->request('post', '/v1/charges', Array, Array) #4
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/halfdrink/stripe-php/lib/ApiOperations/Create.php(23):
>   Stripe\ApiResource::_staticRequest('post', '/v1/charges', Array, NULL)
>   5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/fullbrick/thankYou.php(53): Stripe\Charge::create(Array) #6
>    {main} in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/fullbrick/stripe-php/lib/ApiRequestor.php on line
>   181

The code is:

```
<script>
// Errors For Stripe Payment Card Check
card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
if (event.error) {
  displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
} else {
  displayError.textContent = '';
}
});

// Create a token or display an error when the form is submitted.
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
if (result.error) {
  // Inform the customer that there was an error.
  var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
} else {
  // Send the token to your server.
  stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
 }
 });
 });

 function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
 // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
 var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
 var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
 hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
 hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
 hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
 form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

 // Submit the form
 form.submit();
 }


  // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
  var style = {
  base: {
  // Add your base input styles here. For example:
  fontSize: '16px',
  color: "#32325d",
  }
  };

  // Create an instance of the card Element.
  var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

  // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
  card.mount('#card-element');

  </script>

   <form action="thankYou.php" method="post" id="payment-form">
       <span class="bg-danger" id="payment_errors"></span>
       <span class="bg-danger" id="card-errors"></span>

       <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="full_name">Full Name:</label>
                          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="full_name"  id="full_name">
       </div>
       //Same as Email div, phone,address,city,state,zipcode,country,cardname,cardnumber,exp month, exp year, cvc

       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  id="checkout_button" style="display:none;">Check Out >></button>

   </form>
```

On thanYou.php

```
  //Getting Variable details like 

  $full_name = $_POST['full_name']; // same as email,phone, address,city ...

  $metadata = array(
  "cart_id"   => $cart_id,
  "tax"       => $tax,
  "sub_total" => $sub_total,
  );


  // Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
  // See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys

  \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_hiQjZlN9oJ9GcLGAlPVwAvfq");  // secret Key

   // Token is created using Checkout or Elements!

   // Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
    $token = $_POST['stripeToken']; // Here not getting token
    var_dump($token);

     try{ . // Here not getting inside the try because token is null

     $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([

     'amount' => 999,
     'currency' => 'usd',
     'description' => 'Example charge',
     'source' => $token,
     'receipt_email' => $email,
     'metadata' => $metadata,
     ]);
     }catch(\Stripe\Error\card $e){
     echo $e;
      }
```

This ApiRequestor.php is the main problem I guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined index error PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613570/undefined-index-error-php)

Comment: @ B001ᛦ 1 no I am getting product details on thankyou.php. The problem is after submitting the form THE TOKEN is not generated. I followed all instructions from stripe documentation.

Comment: maybe it could be that your model is not billable. There should be some source or customer. Check the stripe php docs to guide you https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/php

Comment: Could you provide the full and exact code you're using? Also, note that you're getting an API error from Stripe : https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/iar_cuGvSG7abb9bzS which likely means your charge script is not passing the token correctly

Comment: error messages are useful but only thing which is actually fixable is the code. Since we can't see it, it's going to be very hard to fix it. Please provide some relevant code if you need further help. Thanks.

Comment: you do not pass correct POST parameter, and token is null