# Pre-filling php form on update

Tags: php, oop, sql-update, crud

I am currently using one form only for both updating and inserting, it works well. But I would like to have it prefilled when updating only. I am not exactly sure how to do this. If I set the value with the php variable I get an error in the log that states it is not defined. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the form:

```
<?php 
include_once('Crud_class.php');
$obj = new Crud("loocalhost","root","password","mydb");
$id = $_GET['id'];
if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0) {
  echo "Update for record id#:" . $_GET['id'];
} else {
  echo "Insert new book";
}
 ?>

 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Add New Product</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <form method="post" action="actions.php">
 <ul class="form">

   <li><label for"title">Title:</label>
      <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title?>" /></li>

    <li><label for="author">Author:</label>
    <input type="text" name="author"/></li>

     <li><label for="category">Category:</label>
     <select name="category">
       <option value="General">General</option>
       <option value="HTML/CSS">HTML/CSS</option>
       <option value="Javascript">Javascript</option>
       <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
       <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select></li>

   <li><label for"description">Description:</label>
   <textarea name="description"></textarea></li>

   <li><label for="img_path">Image Path:</label>
    <input type="text" name="img_path"/></li>

      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php if ($id > 0) { echo $id;} else {echo 0;} ?>"/>
     <li><input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/></li>
 </ul>
 </form>

  </body>
  </html>
```

and here is my actions file:

```
<?php
include('Crud_class.php');
$obj=new Crud("localhost","root","password","mydb");
if (isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] > 0) {
//update
extract($_REQUEST);
$obj->update($id,$title,$author,$category,$description,$img_path);

} else {
// insert
extract($_REQUEST); 
$obj->insert($title,$author,$category,$description,$img_path);
 }

?>
```

and my crud file

```
       <?php
class Crud{
public $mysqli;
public $data;
public function __construct($host,$username,$password,$db_name){
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'mydb');            
}

// BOOKS Table
//READ
public function readAll(){
    $query="SELECT * FROM books";
    $result= $this->mysqli->query($query);
    $num_result=$result->num_rows;      

    if($num_result>0){
        while($rows=$result->fetch_assoc()){        
            $this->data[]=$rows;
            //print_r($rows);
        }       
        return $this->data;
    }
}
//INSERT
public function insert($title,$author,$category,$description,$img_path){
    $query="INSERT INTO books SET title='$title', author='$author', category='$category', description='$description', img_path='$img_path'";
    $result= $this->mysqli->query($query) or die(mysqli_connect_errno()."Product Failed to Insert");

    if($result){
        header('location:read.php?insert_status=success');  
    }
}
//UPDATE
    public function update($id,$title,$author,$category,$description,$img_path){
        $query="UPDATE books SET title='$title', author='$author', category='$category', description='$description', img_path='$img_path' WHERE id='$id'";
        $result= $this->mysqli->query($query) or die(mysqli_connect_errno()."Cannot update");

        if($result){
            header('location:read.php?update_status=success');  
        }
    } 
//Delete
public function delete($id){
    $query="DELETE FROM books WHERE id='$id'";      
    $result= $this->mysqli->query($query) or die(mysqli_connect_errno()."Failed to Delete");

    if($result){
        header('location:read.php?delete_status=success');  
    }               
}


}




 ?>
```

Comment: What is not defined?  Please include the complete error from your log.

Comment: [Thu Jan 09 09:44:43 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: title in /home/prissipix/Projects/BTS_Bookshelf/form.php on line 39, referer: http://127.0.0.1/Projects/BTS_Bookshelf/read.php?update_status=success

Comment: Sounds like your form hasn't been POSTed yet, so $_POST['title'] doesn't exist.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465728/php-error-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the data from the record that someone is editing on the form page.

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0) {
  echo "Update for record id#:" . $_GET['id'];
  // GET row from database, something like $obj->read($_GET['id']);
}
```

For this you need to add some read-function to your CRUD class which selects a line where id= some input integer.

If you have the data, fetch it to an object or array and use these values in the form:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php if (isset($data)) echo $data['author']; ?>">
```

(of course the select box needs a bit more work)

Answer (score 1):

You've already got your ID and conditions set up. Now you need to initialize the vars you will need:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0) {
  echo "Update for record id#:" . $_GET['id'];
  $formValues = readRecordByID($_GET['id']);  // you will need to create this crud select function
} else {
  echo "Insert new book";
  //initialize blank values:
  $formValues = array(
        'author'=>'',
        'category'=>'',
        'description'=>'',
        'img_path'=>'');
}
```

Now in your form it is safe to use:

```
<input type="text" name="author" value="$formValues['author']"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefilling a form depends either on embedding the prefill contents in the HTML with attributes such as the `value=` attribute for text boxes or setting `selected="selected"` on an `option` in a `<select>`, or on having client-side javascript do that based on data either retrieved via AJAX or, again, embedded in the HTML.

Your `Title` field in the form php is an example of what I'm talking about -- you've got this:

```
value="<?php echo $title?>"
```

and that's what you'd need for all the rest of the fields (and `selected="selected"` for the `<select>` fields).

Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465728/php-error-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: right, but doing it this way give me an error stating the variable is not defined. I have seen done before when two forms are used one for insert and one for update, but can't seem to get it to work when using one form. I also tried value="<?php echo $_GET['title']?>" with no luck :/

Comment: As commented on your question, what is the complete error message?  What variable is not defined?

Comment: the title variable is not defined. Here is the complete error message [Thu Jan 09 09:44:43 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice: Undefined index: title in /home/prissipix/Projects/BTS_Bookshelf/form.php on line 39, referer: 127.0.0.1/Projects/BTS_Bookshelf/read.php?

Comment: That's not what the error message says.  The error message says undefined *index*.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I am totally new to php and just trying to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

changing the php to

```
<?php 
include_once('Crud_class.php');
$obj = new Crud("loocalhost","root","password","mydb");
$id = $_GET['id'];

if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0) {
echo "Update for record id#:" . $_GET['id'];
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){ // this is added
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$result=$obj->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE id='$id'");

$rows=$result->fetch_assoc();

extract($rows);
} else {
  echo "Insert new book";
}
?>
```

and input value to

```
     value="<?php echo $title; ?>"
```

Works!

Thanks everyone for all your help and input! :)

Comment: still having issues with the select box, but the rest works fine