# I am working on create invoice form, gives me 500 undefined index error

Tags: php, yii, undefined, invoice

I am working on create invoice form,
it retrieves the data from 2 models Invoice and InvoiceDetail 
when I submit the form, it gives me the

> error 500: undefined index:site_name.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Invoice;
    $detail = new InvoiceDetail();

    if(isset($_POST['Invoice']))
    {

        $model->attributes=$_POST['Invoice'];

            if(isset($_POST['InvoiceDetail'])){

                $detail = $_POST['InvoiceDetail'];
                foreach($detail as $key=>$details){
                    $det = new InvoiceDetail();
                    $det->attributes = array(

                        'invoice_id' => $model->id,
                        'site_name' => $detail['site_name'][$key],
                        'do_number' => $detail['do_number'][$key],
                        'description' => $detail['description'][$key],
                        'quantity' => $detail['quantity'][$key],
                        'rate' => $detail['rate'][$key],
                        'amount' => isset($detail['amount'][$key])?$detail['amount'][$key]:NULL,
                    );

                    $det->save(false);
                }

            }


        }


    $this->layout='columnInvoice';
    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'detail' => $detail
    ));
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP error: Notice: Undefined index:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465728/php-error-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$detail[$key]['site_name']` not `$detail['site_name'][$key]`.

But you could also use `$details['site_name']`